# PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied - Python 3.7 Twitch Bot

Tags: python, windows, tkinter

new coder here. Searched SO a bunch and googled, but am stumped.

**Goal**: Create a script that launches pipenv, and a custom twitch bot using tkinter.

```
"""dbot_script.py"""
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
import runpy

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=300)
canvas1.pack()


def activate_dbot():
    subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dbot-T1lnEOta'])
    runpy.run_path(r'C:\Users\user\dbot\bot.py')


button1 = tk.Button(text='Activate dbot', command=activate_dbot, bg='brown', fg='white')
canvas1.create_window(150, 150, window=button1)

root.mainloop()
```

**Expected result:** the pipenv will launch, then the tkinter interface which runs the bot will launch.

**Actual result:** Tkinter interface with button appears, no evidence of the pipenv launching shows. Eror message: PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied in terminal.

The bot runs fine when I run:

```
pipenv run python bot.py
```

in the command line, but when I try to activate it through a tkinter interface, I get the error message stated above. I have tried running the command line in adminstrator mode as well.

The module I am using to connect to twitch is twitchio and I do have access to my oauth key.

Full Error Message:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\user\dbot\dbot_script.py", line 12, in activate_dbot
    subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dbot-T1lnEOta'])
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 323, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

Comment: Have you checked the permissions on `C:\Users\user\dbot\bot.py` and `C:\Users\user\.virtualenvs\dbot-T1lnEOta`? For further help it would be nice if you could provide the full traceback of the error too

Comment: Thank you for helping. Just checked permissions on both folders, and they have the same permissions: NT AUTHORITY SYSTEM Allow FullControl. Will edit the post to include the full traceback error.